# add_rewrite_rule not working for me

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, query-string

I have the following rewrite tags defined:

```
// ADD REWRITE TAG FOR 'VEHICLE MAKES'
add_rewrite_tag('%make%','([^&]+)');

// ADD REWRITE TAG FOR 'BODY STYLES'
add_rewrite_tag('%body-style%','([^&]+)');

// ADD REWRITE TAG FOR 'OTHER TOPICS'
add_rewrite_tag('%topic%','([^&]+)');
```

I'm trying to create a custom rewrite for each one of these that can apply to any page the variables exist.

I've been reworking the WP example in the documentation with no luck.. This rewrite is for 'Vehicle Makes'.

I'm aiming for WP to interpret the following:

```
http://example.com/make/abc
```

as

```
http://example.com?make=abc
```

and the same pattern for

`http://example.com?body-style=abc` & `http://example.com?topic=abc`

I can't seem to get the following to work no matter how much I try

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
```

Any and All help is appreciated!

Comment: How did you go with this @AustinTBiggs?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the third parameter to that call?

`add_rewrite_tag( '%make%', '([^/]+)', 'make=' );`

Answer (score 0):

The way of using `add_rewrite_rule` function is given below:

1. Hook this function into the `init` hook
2. Use `query_vars` filter to make the new rewrite available in the `query_vars`

**Here is the code snippet**

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_rule');
function my_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'make/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?make=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'my_rewrite_query_var');
function my_rewrite_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'make';
    return $vars;
}
```

Now, go to permalink settings page, and click on `Save Changes` to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: Comes out blank when you try and do a `get_query_var('make')`

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules?

Answer (score -1):

Before asking any question here, please try to find it out yourself. In case of wordpress you should look at http://codex.wordpress.org/ first.

Most of the answers are available already.

The piece of code you are looking for is a function **flush_rewrite_rules()**.

Ref: [Rewrite Rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

Comment: That is incorrect, I did a lot of searching for the correct answer and it's not simply flushing the rewrite rules. I always flush rules after they've been modified.